# What does a "git repository" refer to precisely?

Tags: git

Suppose my working directory `working_directory` has a `.git` hidden subdirectory (created with `git init`) and nothing else.

What is referred to by our "git repository"?  Is it the hidden `.git` folder, or the entire contents of `working_directory` which merely includes the `.git` subfolder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the entire contents of the **working directory**, that would be considered the repository.

Think about it like this:  When you **clone** a repository, you're not just "copying" the `.git` folder, you're pulling down the entire "repository" in the sense of the entire root, all subfolders, and files that live in the repository.

Take a look at [GitHub's awesome definition on "repository"](https://help.github.com/articles/github-glossary/#repository) (copied here for direct reference):

> A repository is the most basic element of GitHub. ***They're easiest to imagine as a project's folder. A repository contains all of the project files (including documentation), and stores each file's revision history***. Repositories can have multiple collaborators and can be either public or private.

Even though there is a lot of mention of "GitHub" in this answer, it is worth noting that the *repository* is an element of the Git SCM.  Of course GitHub inherits this as well naturally, but it is a Git thing at the root of it all.

To further expand on this and to give the **root** definition, see the following [official Git SCM definition on "repository"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_repository) (copy/pasted for direct reference):

> A collection of refs together with an object database containing all objects which are reachable from the refs, possibly accompanied by meta data from one or more porcelains. A repository can share an object database with other repositories via alternates mechanism.

With that being said, without knowledge of Git that definition will probably make you think you know even less of what a repository is.  There are a lot of *other* git definitions you need to know in order to understand that particular one.

Comment: *It is the entire contents of the working directory [...]* I disagree. Would you say that a clone created with `git clone --bare` is not a Git repository because it's missing the working directory?

Comment: @Jubobs I would say that would be considered a "bare repository".

Answer (score 0):

The respository is the bit that has the stored copy (just like a depository), so it the .git folder, while the worktree (correctly: working tree) is the contents of the parent folder (excluding the .git folder).

That said, the linguistic confusion is very common.

Try `git help glossary` to see some of the confusing terms explained in a little more detail.

Likewise `git help -g` will list most of the relevant guides (such as the `specifying revisions` guide).